# Can't get error_tag to work in elixir phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Given I have a template

```
    <%= label f, :who_person do
        [content_tag(:span, "What is your name?"), text_input(f, :who_person)]
    end %>
    <%= error_tag f, :who_person %>
```

And a model with the attribute

```
@required_fields ~w(who_person)
```

Can anyone tell me why, when I submit the field empty, does an error message *not* appear?

If I use validations inside the changeset of the model, then proper error messages appear, but not when I rely on the optional and required fields.

Being very very new to Elixir, this has me completely stumped.

Comment: Could you provide whole code of your model and action youre using in your example?

Comment: I think it just sends an empty string as the input and thus it's not nil, you might use `scrub_params` in the controller to turn empty strings to nils and then changeset will produce an error.